# Bash and key value pair or a map

Tags: bash, shell-script

We are writing a bash script which basically does the job of python dictionary. Below is the code siffet we are using and the expected output.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A serviceTag
serviceTag["source"]="ccr"
declare -A services
services+=( ["dataservice"]="latest" )

serviceTag+=( ["services"]=services )

echo "$serviceTag"
```

The expected output is

```
{"source":"ccr","services":{"datasetvice":"latest"}}
```

But what we are getting is

```
ccrservices
```

Can somebody help us in what mistake we are doing here and how can we achieve this using bash and its code?

Regards,
Kanthu

Comment: That and `services` is just the string `services` - you need array expansion for that as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get it. Can you pls suggest me the code changes?

Comment: `printf '{"%s":"%s","%s":"%s":{"%s":"%s"}}\n' "${!serviceTag[@]}" "${serviceTag[@]}" "${!services[@]}" "${services[@]}"`

Comment: @jet I reopened it, you can post that as an answer

Comment: Using `$avar` instead of `${avar[@]}` with an array `avar` refers to its first entry, not to the whole array, and you are NOT getting that output (`ccrservices`) from the code you have posted. But, [as already said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/575224/308316), bash's arrays are unidimensional, so that will not work, anyways.

Comment: Thaks Mosvy for your comment. If its an unidimensional, then I will have to look for other options on scripting.

Answer (score 2):

According to the GNU project's Bash reference manual, [Bash's arrays are one-dimensional](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html), whether they be indexed or associative. That means you can't nest them. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I don't think what you're trying to do is possible.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try.

```
printf '{"%s":"%s","%s":"%s":{"%s":"%s"}}\n' "${!serviceTag[@]}" "${serviceTag[@]}" "${!services[@]}" "${services[@]}"
```

Comment: This is ending up with ```{"ccrservices":"ccrservices","latest":"latest":{"":""}}```

Comment: How can I access this this with key value pair.. ??

Comment: really, my output is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, your suggested printf I am trying and ended up wih ```{"0":"ccrservices","0":"latest":{"":""}}``` output. But this not we are looking. We are expecting ```{"source":"ccr","services":{"datasetvice":"latest"}}```.

Comment: The output you posted is what I get on this side.

Comment: Otherwise I would not have posted my answer... I have tested on both my linux machines and FreeBSD both have bashv5+.

Comment: Strange. I am using MAC and bas version GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0)

Comment: You might have 2 bash installed since the default bash on Mac is bashv3. Make sure you're really using bashv5+,  try `type -a bash` and see what is the output.

Comment: Here is the output along with bash version.

Comment: ```                                                                                                                KAVIRUPA-M-J0NZ:microk8s-deployments kavirupa$ bash kanthu.sh 
5.0.16(1)-release
{"source":"services","ccr":"services":{"0":"latest"}}
KAVIRUPA-M-J0NZ:microk8s-deployments kavirupa$ 
KAVIRUPA-M-J0NZ:microk8s-deployments kavirupa$                                              
 ```

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a task thats appropriate for shell scripting. Do yourself a favor, and
use a programming language for this task. For example with PHP:

```
<?php
$services = ['dataservive' => 'latest'];
$serviceTag['source'] = 'ccr';
$serviceTag['services'] = $services;
# example 1
print_r($serviceTag);
# exmaple 2
echo json_encode($serviceTag), "\n";
```

Result:

```
Array (
   [source] => ccr
   [services] => Array (
      [dataservive] => latest
   )
)
{"source":"ccr","services":{"dataservive":"latest"}}
```